# One Submit Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, submit

I have two textboxes and two submit buttons.  Each button submits the information in the textbox, I would like to have 1 submit button that submits both texboxes at once without.  The problem is, if one textbox is empty then it overwrites the data with empty data.  I would like it only to submit information if there's something in the textbox.  Some pseudocode code might help:

- if textbox1 is empty then do nothing, if textbox2 has data then update database.
- if textbox1 has data then update if textbox2 is empty then do not update textbox2.

Here is my code, I hope what i'm saying makes sense.

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            SqlConnection conns = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDBConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE test SET SitUps = @SitUps WHERE (Id = @Id)", conns);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            Label IdL = ((Label)FormView1.FindControl("IdLabel"));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", IdL.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SitUps", Sits.Text);
            conns.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Label17.Text = "Successfully Submitted Sit-Ups!";

    }

    protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            SqlConnection conns = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDBConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE test SET pushUps = @pushUps WHERE (Id = @Id)", conns);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            Label IdL = ((Label)FormView1.FindControl("IdLabel"));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", IdL.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pushUps", Push.Text);
            conns.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Label18.Text = "Successfully Submitted Push-Ups!";

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just need to add if(Push.Text!="") and  if(Sits.Text!="") before each of the blocks you trying to run

Answer (score 2):

Replace it with this:

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
//check Sits and Push empty or not
if(Sits.Text!="") 
{
//update Sits here
}

if(Push.Text!="") 
 {
//update Push here
 }
    }
```